# AWS Labmda Java HttpURLConnection timeout

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

Here is my Lambda code

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class CallURL implements RequestHandler<Void, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Void input, Context context) {
        try {
            String vAdress = "https://www.google.com";
            //context.getLogger().log("URL: " + vAdress+"\n");

            URL vURL = new URL(vAdress);
            //context.getLogger().log("Open connection\n");
            HttpURLConnection vConnection = (HttpURLConnection) vURL.openConnection();
            vConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            vConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            vConnection.connect();
            return String.valueOf(vConnection.getResponseCode()) +" : "+ vConnection.getResponseMessage();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            return ioe.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great till this line

```
HttpURLConnection vConnection = (HttpURLConnection) vURL.openConnection();
```

When i try to test this function i have every time timeout error.

```
"errorMessage": "2017-11-29T08:36:22.020Z 5ea45429-d4e0-11e7-8749-31e92e6a27f6 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
```

I have selected "No VPC" in lambda settings. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was connected with not enough memory allocated for lambda function.
I have changed from 128mb to 512mb and it works

Answer (score 0):

All calls made to AWS Lambda must complete execution within 300 seconds. The default timeout is 3 seconds, but you can set the timeout to any value between 1 and 300 seconds.

Refer:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions.html

Comment: I have use default Lambda timeout 3 seconds. Problem not here. Problem in HttpURLConnection, lambda can't connect to any url's. I think some additional config needed but i have no idea what

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove vConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000); or increase number from 1000 to a bigger number.

If that doesn't work; try to increase Lambda execution time from 3 secs to 10 seconds. Just to make sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Done. Result the same.
In my desktop java app, i use the same code and it works perfect, no any timeout. Looks like Amazon block something

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply switch my url from https to http and it works.

```
private byte[] download(String tickerUrl, String file) throws IOException {
    String url = "http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EURONEXT/FP.csv?api_key=API_KEY"
    return  ByteStreams.toByteArray(new URL(url).openStream());
}
```

My lambda runs in No VPC environnement.
I have changed from 128mb to    512mb with no results.
https url works like a charm locally in my    IDE.